# Create a Conection TimeOut using urllib2.urlOpen()

Tags: python, connection-timeout, urlopen

I want to create a connection timeout exception using urlopen.

try:
    urllib2.urlopen("http://example.com", timeout = 5)
except urllib2.URLError, e:
    raise MyException("There was an error: %r" % e)

This is the code

I want to create a timeout that this code would bring an exception.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Use request (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) lib...it's best!

Answer (score 1):

You need to catch **socket.timeout** exception, check example below.

```
import urllib2
import socket

class MyException(Exception):
    pass

try:
    urllib2.urlopen("http://example.com", timeout = 1)
except socket.timeout, e:
    # For Python 2.7
    raise MyException("There was an error: %r" % e)
```

I strongly recommend using [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library for making requests, it will make your life easier.

Comment: See the thing is i want to make the timeout.. The status of request is 200 OK. I want to hold up a connection so that it creates a timeout Exception.

Comment: That's an unusual case..
Maybe You could raise timeout exception by yourself.
Create a custom timeout exception (like in my example MyExcepton) and then raise it after urlopen. I don't think there is an option to "hold" connection.

Comment: okay thanks for you response.  i know i've been a bit dumb asking this... lol